# Laravel BelongsTo and hasOne Model Relationship returns Null

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am wondering why my Models returns null when requested record does not exist in database table instead of returning empty collection or empty Model instance.

Here are my models

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,   AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'email',
        'password',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'state_id'
    ];

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State','state_id','id');
    }
}

class State extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'country_id',
        'active'];
}
```

States Table

```
 id   name     country_id  active
 1    texas    1           1
 2    alaska   1           1
```

Users Table

```
 id   first_name  state_id
 1    frank       null
```

Here is the problem or is this how it's meant to behave?

```
$user = User::with('state')->get(); //returns null

$user->state->name; //surely throws an exception

//I don't want to do this or MUST I?:
if (is_object($user))
    $state = $user->state->name;
```

I expected Laravel to return an empty Collection when `state_id` of a **user** does not exist in states table instead null is being returned,

The issue I have with this is, I am using a Transformer which expects an instance of `state model` and not a null

```
public function includeState(User $model)
{
    $state = $model->state; //null is being returned here
    return $this->item($state, new StateTransformer); //this throws an exception when it receives null
}
```

see: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this:

```
if(!$state = $model->state) {
   $state = new State();
}
```

Or, this might work

`$state = ($model->state != null ? $model->state : new State());`

---

If you are just getting one user, you don't need eager loading `with()`.

Just do:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->state->name
```

When you do `$user = User::with('state')->get();` you get a collection of ALL users. So `$user->state` wouldn't work.

Comment: Nice idea but I think you are missing a point which is the relationship. When you do `new State()` you are building a new object. It could be used like this dough `$state = new State(); $state->find($model->state_id);` however null will still be returned

Comment: `$user = User::with('state')->get();` - This returns all your users, not one user. So `$users` would be more applicable, and you would need a foreach loop to output `$user->state->name`. Updated my answer to include that. Hopefully that was your problem

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sometimes returns null `$user = User::with('state')->get();` because there is no need to specify the keys when using belongsTo, unless is different from id. So from :

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State','state_id','id');
}
```

To:

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State');
}
```

This should do the trick.

You need to loop through users to get the state for each user.

Comment: Is that indented or a bug? Seems very strange if it's intended.

Comment: I dont know, maybe. I used to have the same problem.

Comment: @chronos there are no difference between the two. You may decide to specify a foreign key or laravel will assume something like`user_id`.. `$this->hbelongsTo('App\Models\State', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`